# saving webpages with a unique name in python

Tags: python, loops, selenium-webdriver, iteration

I have encountered the issue when looping over webpages in selenium.
I am trying to 1) upload a webpage (say, this one https://miet.ru/news/www.alcon.ru/?PAGEN_1=2) that contains many hrefs with /news/ identificator like this: a href="/news/153163"
2) second, I tell selenium to click on each of these hrefs (as a rule, there are 20 of them on each webpage) and download this page, save it with a specific name

```
ser = Service(r"/usr/local/bin/chromedriver.exe")
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
prefs = {"pageLoadStrategy" : "eager"}
op.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=op)

p3 = range(2,33) #there are 31 webpages that contain hrefs
p2 = range(1,21) #on every webpage there are 20 hrefs, each has xpath
p4 = range(1,621) #i need to save each page (hrefs) and give it a unique number. as each page of 31 will have 20 hrefs = 620

for y in p3: #open a webpage from 2 to 32
    address = os.path.join(f"https://miet.ru/news/www.alcon.ru/?PAGEN_1={y}")
    driver.get(address)
    for i in p2: #search for hrefs using xpath and click on it, then save, go back to a webpage
        element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'/html/body/main/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[{i}]/div[2]/div/a').click()
        for x in p4:
            n = os.path.join(f"/Users/dariagerashchenko/PycharmProjects/svo/миэт_news/page_{x}.html")
        f = codecs.open(n, "w", "utf−8")
        h = driver.page_source
        f.write(h)
        driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

I wish I could save each html with a unique number from 1 to 620, but the code I have written saves each href 620 times.
Say, html pages from webpage https://miet.ru/news/www.alcon.ru/?PAGEN_1=2 will be called 1.html, 2.html (...) 20.html
while htmls from webpage https://miet.ru/news/www.alcon.ru/?PAGEN_1=3 will be called 21.html, 22.html (...) and so on with other pages.

Any ideas? I think the answer is quite easy, however, I do not find it.

Comment: You seem to be asking a general coding / coding language specific question... would it not be good to rather tag this question as a Python question as well?

Comment: @BernardV thank you, can you please take a look at my code? I tried to clarify what I want

Comment: You need to work on the quality and clarity of your question. 1. Give variables a meaningful name to help your question be more clear, example instead of calling something `p3 = range(2,33)` call it: `webpagesRange = range(2,33)` 2. Your comments are contradicting each other, in one comment you state: `#there are 31 webpages that contain hrefs` then you state:  `as each page of 33 will have 20 hrefs = 660`, the question is not clear enough.

Comment: @BernardV my bad, I confused the numbers. Essentially, I want the following: Say, html pages from webpage https://miet.ru/news/www.alcon.ru/?PAGEN_1=2 will be called 1.html, 2.html (...) 20.html while htmls from webpage https://miet.ru/news/www.alcon.ru/?PAGEN_1=3 will be called 21.html, 22.html (...) and so on with other pages.

Comment: save your filenames with current date/time will help to avoid dupes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, the answer is smth along these lines:

```
p3 = range(2,33) #there are 31 webpages that contain hrefs
p2 = range(1,21) #on every webpage there are 20 hrefs, each has xpath
x = 1
for y in p3: #open a webpage from 2 to 32
    address = os.path.join(f"https://miet.ru/news/www.alcon.ru/?PAGEN_1={y}")
    driver.get(address)
    for i in p2: #search for hrefs using xpath and click on it, then save, go back to a webpage
        element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'/html/body/main/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[{i}]/div[2]/div/a').click()
        x += 1
        n = os.path.join(f"/Users/dariagerashchenko/PycharmProjects/svo/миэт_news/page_{x}.html")
        f = codecs.open(n, "w", "utf−8")
        h = driver.page_source
        f.write(h)
        driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```